# Double "new contributor" message

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, new-contributor-indicator

If I try to post two comments in a row on a question asked by a new user, I get a double "new contributor" thingy when I try to post the second comment:

[image: Double message screenshot]

This was on Firefox 116.0.3. I don't know if the problem happens on other browsers.

Comment: Cross-site dupe: [So nice, we said it twice: "User is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392049/so-nice-we-said-it-twice-user-is-a-new-contributor-be-nice-and-check-out-ou)

Answer (score 10):

This has been fixed in revision 2024.1.9.3159. When closing the dialog, we were making the template (the top one) visible. This way, when showing a form next time we were showing the notification twice...